# Is there possibility to assign a value to Android Button in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've just started learning about Xamarin Android. I've got few buttons with the same click event handler.

```
private Button flipper1Btn;
    private Button flipper2Btn;
    private ViewFlipper flipper;
    private TextView text;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        setControls();
        setEvents();
    }

    private void setControls()
    {
        flipper = FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.viewFlipper1);
        flipper1Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        flipper2Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

    }
    private void setEvents()
    {
        flipper1Btn.Click += FlipperBtn_Click;
        flipper2Btn.Click += FlipperBtn_Click;
    }

    #region Events

    private void FlipperBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button sendBtn = (Button)sender;       
    }

    #endregion
```

In "FlipperBtn_Click" method I would like to recognize which button was pressed and get value from this button. I would like to achieve something like in HTML5 by assign to div as many attribute I want. I was thinking about android "Tag" propertie, and trying to do something like this:

```
private void setControls()
    {
        flipper = FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.viewFlipper1);
        flipper1Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        flipper2Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        FlipperBtnTag tag1 = new FlipperBtnTag("tag1", "tag1Value");
        FlipperBtnTag tag2 = new FlipperBtnTag("tag2", "tag2Value");

        flipper1Btn.SetTag(1, tag1);
        flipper1Btn.SetTag(2, tag2);
    }
```

Bud I don't understand few thinks:
a) What is a purpose of using "key" in SetTag method?
b) How Can I convert c# class object into Java.Lang.Object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to set tags in the buttons to find witch is being clicked.

Do this:

```
flipper1Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
flipper2Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);

flipper1Btn += Button_Click;
flipper2Btn += Button_Click;

void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    switch (button.Id)
    {
        case Resource.Id.button1:
            // Do Stuff here
        break;

        case Resource.Id.button2:
            // Do Stuff here
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

---

In Xamarin Android you have two ways to set tags.
Via [property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Tag/) or via [method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.SetTag/p/System.Int32/Java.Lang.Object/).

```
button.SetTag(1, "value");
```

Or:

```
button.Tag = "value";
```

Comment: Thank You very much! Works as I want :)